# Error with templates on gcc/clang but not on MSVC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++

I am having issues with templates and portability. Given this MVCE:

```
#include <cstdio>

class C
{
public:
    void go()
    {
        printf("go\n");
    }
};

template<typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T* pInstance) : m_pInstance(pInstance)
    {
    }

protected:
    T* m_pInstance;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
    using Base = A<T>;
public:
    B(T* pInstance) : A<T>(pInstance)
    {
    }

    void foo()
    {
        B::m_pInstance->go();
        C* a = nullptr;
        if (a == &B::m_pInstance)
        {
        }

    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    C c;
    B<C> b(&c);
    b.foo();
}
```

I get the error:

```
main.cpp:37:9: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('C *' and 'C *A<C>::*')
                if (a == &B::m_pInstance)
                    ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:48:4: note: in instantiation of member function 'B<C>::foo' requested here
        b.foo();
          ^
1 error generated.
```

But I am not sure why I get this? Ok I see how the types are different but why would the latter being a member cause this problem? Visual Studio (which of course does have a different template engine) handles the same fine.

Comment: Actually, this code *does not* build with Visual C++ 2013, 2015, or 2017: ``main.cpp(37): error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'C *A<T>::* ' to 'C *'``. With VC 2012 you get a different error: ``error C2873: 'Base' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&B::m_pInstance` is pointer to data member. You either have to change it to

```
if (a == this->B::m_pInstance)
```

or

```
if (a == B::m_pInstance)
```

If you want to compare them as pointer-to-members you have to change `a`'s type like:

```
    T* (A<T>::*a) = nullptr;
```

or

```
    C* (A<C>::*a) = nullptr;
```

Comment: Ok :( I understood that using `B::` eliminates the need for `this->` (none of which are needed on MSVC). Why is not does `B::` work when invoking the `go()` method but not for the comparison?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis: MSVC does not implement two phase lookup correctly, thus you don't need `this->` to make it a dependent name. That is however wrong.

Comment: @Jaa-c yeah well, I though the issue was that the type was not dedepndant, but  the `this->B::` construction just seems ugly, but again, I'm coming from mostly a MSVC background.

Answer (score 0):

How MSVC handles that, I do not know -- but it sure is a bug.

`&B::m_pInstance` happens to be the syntax to form a pointer-to-member. You can disambiguate it to get the plain member access you expect with `&(B::m_pInstance)`, but this then reveals another issue:

```
main.cpp:37:15: error: comparison of distinct pointer types ('C *' and 'C **')
        if (a == &(B::m_pInstance))
            ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I guess what you really want is `if(a == B::m_pInstance)`.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis if you really want a pointer-to-member (`C *A<C>::*`), it is unclear to me what you expect from comparing it to a `C*`. Don't you want the value of the member instead?

Comment: Nope, the real case is where I have a event queue, to which I add events and have a wait function which returns the event pointer that popped out, and I want to check if that is the same event, which is the member of the parent. I could of course dereference it and add an equality operator, but there is not much sense in that.

Comment: Again, sorry about my MVCE, the original code does not have a `T*` but a `T`. Sorry for that, I edited the snippet multiple times to remove the unneeded stuff and messed up a bit in the end.